# Function takes screenshot of the left top corner only

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This is the screenshot my program takes:

[image: description]

I try to make a C++ program that takes a screenshot and saves it as png. Everthing works except it takes a screenshot of just the top left of the screen.

The problem is that my application takes a picture of the top left corner of my desktop.

How can I take a screenshot of the WHOLE screen? What do I have to change in my code to reach my goal?

This is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")

int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid) {
    UINT num = 0;
    UINT size = 0;
    Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    Gdiplus::GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if (size == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    pImageCodecInfo = (Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if (pImageCodecInfo == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);

    for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j) {
        if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0) {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;
        }
    }

    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return -1;
}

void TakeScreenshot(const wchar_t* file_name) {
    // Get the dimensions of the whole desktop
    int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);

    // Create a bitmap to hold the screenshot
    HDC screen_dc = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC mem_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(screen_dc);
    HBITMAP bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(screen_dc, width, height);
    HGDIOBJ old_bitmap = SelectObject(mem_dc, bitmap);

    // Copy the screen contents to the bitmap
    BitBlt(mem_dc, 0, 0, width, height, screen_dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // Save the bitmap to a file
    Gdiplus::Bitmap image(bitmap, NULL);
    CLSID png_clsid;
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &png_clsid);
    image.Save((WCHAR*)file_name, &png_clsid, NULL);

    // Clean up
    SelectObject(mem_dc, old_bitmap);
    DeleteObject(bitmap);
    DeleteDC(mem_dc);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, screen_dc);
}

int main()
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    TakeScreenshot(L"test.png");

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

Updated code:
I tried using `GetDpiForSystem()` because my application should be DPI-aware. But still same result.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")

int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
    UINT num = 0;
    UINT size = 0;
    Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    Gdiplus::GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if (size == 0) {
        printf("Error: GetImageEncodersSize returned size 0\n");
        return -1;
    }

    pImageCodecInfo = (Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if (pImageCodecInfo == NULL) {
        printf("Error: malloc failed to allocate memory for ImageCodecInfo\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo) != Ok) {
        printf("Error: GetImageEncoders failed\n");
        free(pImageCodecInfo);
        return -1;
    }

    for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j) {
        if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0) {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;
        }
    }

    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return -1;
}

void TakeScreenshot(const wchar_t* file_name)
{
    // Get the dimensions of the whole desktop
    int dpi_x = GetDpiForSystem();
    int dpi_y = GetDpiForSystem();
    int width = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CXSCREEN, dpi_x);
    int height = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CYSCREEN, dpi_y);

    if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
        printf("Error: GetSystemMetrics returned invalid screen dimensions\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Width: %d\n", width);
    printf("Height: %d\n", height);

    // Create a bitmap to hold the screenshot
    HDC screen_dc = GetDC(NULL);
    if (screen_dc == NULL) {
        printf("Error: GetDC failed to get a handle to the screen device context\n");
        return;
    }

    HDC mem_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(screen_dc);
    if (mem_dc == NULL) {
        printf("Error: CreateCompatibleDC failed to create a compatible device context\n");
        ReleaseDC(NULL, screen_dc);
        return;
    }

    // Create a bitmap that is scaled to the appropriate DPI
    HBITMAP bitmap = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, GetDeviceCaps(screen_dc, BITSPIXEL), NULL);
    if (bitmap == NULL) {
        printf("Error: CreateCompatibleBitmap failed to create a compatible bitmap\n");
        DeleteDC(mem_dc);
        ReleaseDC(NULL, screen_dc);
        return;
    }

    HGDIOBJ old_bitmap = SelectObject(mem_dc, bitmap);

    // Set the DPI of the memory DC to match the system DPI
    SetGraphicsMode(mem_dc, GM_ADVANCED);
    XFORM xform;
    xform.eM11 = (FLOAT)dpi_x / 96;
    xform.eM12 = xform.eM21 = xform.eM22 = 0;
    xform.eDx = xform.eDy = 0;
    SetWorldTransform(mem_dc, &xform);

    // Copy the screen contents to the bitmap
    if (BitBlt(mem_dc, 0, 0, width, height, screen_dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) == 0) {
        printf("Error:BitBlt failed to copy screen contents to bitmap\n");
        return;
    }

    // Save the bitmap to a file
    Gdiplus::Bitmap image(bitmap, NULL);
    if (image.GetLastStatus() != Ok) {
        printf("Error: Bitmap constructor failed to create a Bitmap object\n");
        return;
    }

    CLSID png_clsid;
    int r = GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &png_clsid);
    if (r == -1)
    {
        printf("Error: unable to find image encoder for MIME type 'image/png'\n");
        return;
    }

    if (image.Save(file_name, &png_clsid, NULL) != Ok) {
        printf("Error: Bitmap::Save failed to save image\n");
        return;
    }

    // Clean up
    SelectObject(mem_dc, old_bitmap);
    DeleteObject(bitmap);
    DeleteDC(mem_dc);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, screen_dc);
}

int main()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    TakeScreenshot(L"test.png");

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to include one. We can't tell you what's wrong with your code without seeing your code.

Comment: [High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows).

Comment: Have the pixels in the output bitmap been stretched? Or are they 1 to 1 equivalent to what you see on the screen?

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-bitmap(hbitmap_hpalette)) for the overload of the `Gdiplus::Bitmap` constructor that you are calling states the following: `"Do not pass to the GDI+ Bitmap::Bitmap constructor a GDI bitmap or a GDI palette that is currently (or was previously) selected into a device context."` I believe that you are violating this rule.

Comment: Side note: The documentation that I linked to above also states that you should not call `DeleteObject(bitmap);` until after the `Gdiplus::Bitmap` object goes out of scope. However, I doubt that this is the reason for your problem.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel No, I don't use the StretchBlt funtcion. But I think I don't need that because I use BitBlt()

Comment: @ErlingHaaland: That does not answer my question. My question was whether the output image **has been** stretched, i.e. whether the pixels in the output image are 1 to 1 equivalent to the pixels on the screen, or whether some kind of stretching occurred. If the output image has been stretched for some reason, then this would explain why you only see the top-left corner.

Comment: Oh okay. Yes it is stretched. I don't get a screenshot of just 1px by 1px. I get more then that it's maybe 300px by 500px. I hope this helps.

Comment: The image you posted has a size of 1536*960 pixels. What is the actual resolution of your monitor/desktop?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It is 1536*960

Comment: @ErlingHaaland: Yes, that is correct. That means that your program is reading the correct number of pixels. But for some reason, the pixels have been stretched. What happens if you read more pixels then what was returned by `GetSystemMetrics`? What happens if you set `width = 2000;` and `height = 1500;`? Can you then see more of your desktop?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Then it does get the rest of the screen (not the whole screen ofcourse).

Comment: I'm sorry if I do 2000 and 1500 it gets more then just the screen. The rest is black.

Comment: @ErlingHaaland: But can you now see the bottom and the right side of your desktop? Or is it still only the top-left?

Comment: 2000 and 1500 is very little. When I do 4000 and 3000 I get the full screen plus a little black. But the full screen is visible. So yes I do see the bottom and right of my desktop (if using 4000 and 3000). Note: I'm sure my screen resolution is 1536*960, I confirmed it multiple time throught multiple sources.

Comment: @ErlingHaaland: What if you do exactly double your actual screen resolution? What if you do 3072*1920? Do you get black? Or is the right and/or bottom cut off? Or is it exactly correct?

Comment: I tried that earlier, and now again. I don't get the full screen, the right and bottom is cut off. I get maybe 70% of my screen.

Comment: As I stated in a previous comment, you appear to be violating a rule that is specified in the documentation of the constructor of `Gdiplus::Bitmap`. However, I am not sure how exactly to comply with this rule. Does the behavior change if you add the line `SelectObject(mem_dc, old_bitmap);` immediately after the line that calls `BitBlt`, i.e. before the line `Gdiplus::Bitmap image(bitmap, NULL);`? Even if this has no effect, I believe that you should do this anyway, because the documentation for `SelectObject` says so.

Comment: BitBlt fails if I do that because it needs the old_bitmap

Comment: @ErlingHaaland: Your previous comment does not make sense to me. How can inserting code **after** the call to `BitBlt` cause that function to fail?

Comment: @ErlingHaaland: Ah, I see that you are already calling `SelectObject(mem_dc, old_bitmap);`, but you are doing that after the line `Gdiplus::Bitmap image(bitmap, NULL);`. What I am asking you to do is to move the line `SelectObject(mem_dc, old_bitmap);` immediately before the line `Gdiplus::Bitmap image(bitmap, NULL);`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I was wrong it doens't give an error. When I move SelectObject() before Bitmap image(). It gives a full black screenshot.

Comment: @ErlingHaaland: I find that very strange, because, as previously stated, [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-bitmap(hbitmap_hpalette)) explicitly states that the bitmap should not be selected into a DC when you call the constructor. However, in parentheses, it also states that it should not have previously been selected in one either, which does not make sense to me.

Comment: Please note that someone else has written a comment with a request for clarification, which you have not addressed. You have tagged the question with the language C, but you are using C++ code, which does not make sense. It is unclear whether you are asking for a solution in C or C++. If you do not address such contradictions in your question, then the chance of someone else answering your question may be diminished. My guess is that you want a solution in C++. In that case, you should change the tag from C to C++.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel if you use this code on your computer, what are the results?

Comment: Why not SM_CXFULLSCREEN ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust same result

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I tried it on a vm but i get the same result

Comment: @ErlingHaaland: Your posted code works with me. I am unable to reproduce your problem. However, that does not mean much, because I am using Windows 7 with the desktop compositor deactivated.

Comment: [`GetSystemMetrics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics): *"This API is not DPI aware, and should not be used if the calling thread is per-monitor DPI aware. For the DPI-aware version of this API, see [GetSystemMetricsForDPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetricsfordpi). For more information on DPI awareness, see the [Windows High DPI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows)."*

Comment: @IInspectable I updated my code like this(see above), but still same result.

Comment: I'm just gonna work on something else maybe I will get a hunch. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @ErlingHaaland: According to the documentation for the function [`GetDpiForSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdpiforsystem), calling that function will always return the value `96` unless you make your application DPI-aware. I believe one way of doing this is to call the function [`SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setthreaddpiawarenesscontext).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thank you. Now it works. I'm gonna post my code as answer.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks for your tip. It turned out that you were correct that the issue was due to the DPI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important for the code to be DPI-aware because the DPI of a display can vary from one system to another. For example, a user might have a high-resolution display with a DPI of 192, while another user might have a lower-resolution display with a DPI of 96.

I added this code before calling `TakeScreenshot()`: `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT dpi_awareness_context = SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE);`.

After `TakeScreenshot()` I added: `SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(dpi_awareness_context);`.

This makes sure my application is DPI-aware, as @AndreasWenzel said in the comments.

This code works perfectly:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")

int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
    UINT num = 0;
    UINT size = 0;
    Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    Gdiplus::GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if (size == 0) {
        printf("Error: GetImageEncodersSize returned size 0\n");
        return -1;
    }

    pImageCodecInfo = (Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if (pImageCodecInfo == NULL) {
        printf("Error: malloc failed to allocate memory for ImageCodecInfo\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo) != Ok) {
        printf("Error: GetImageEncoders failed\n");
        free(pImageCodecInfo);
        return -1;
    }

    for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j) {
        if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0) {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;
        }
    }

    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return -1;
}

void TakeScreenshot(const wchar_t* file_name)
{
    // Get the dimensions of the whole desktop
    int dpi_x = GetDpiForSystem();
    int dpi_y = GetDpiForSystem();
    int width = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CXSCREEN, dpi_x);
    int height = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CYSCREEN, dpi_y);

    if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
        printf("Error: GetSystemMetrics returned invalid screen dimensions\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Width: %d\n", width);
    printf("Height: %d\n", height);

    // Create a bitmap to hold the screenshot
    HDC screen_dc = GetDC(NULL);
    if (screen_dc == NULL) {
        printf("Error: GetDC failed to get a handle to the screen device context\n");
        return;
    }

    HDC mem_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(screen_dc);
    if (mem_dc == NULL) {
        printf("Error: CreateCompatibleDC failed to create a compatible device context\n");
        ReleaseDC(NULL, screen_dc);
        return;
    }

    // Create a bitmap that is scaled to the appropriate DPI
    HBITMAP bitmap = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, GetDeviceCaps(screen_dc, BITSPIXEL), NULL);
    if (bitmap == NULL) {
        printf("Error: CreateCompatibleBitmap failed to create a compatible bitmap\n");
        DeleteDC(mem_dc);
        ReleaseDC(NULL, screen_dc);
        return;
    }

    HGDIOBJ old_bitmap = SelectObject(mem_dc, bitmap);

    // Set the DPI of the memory DC to match the system DPI
    SetGraphicsMode(mem_dc, GM_ADVANCED);
    XFORM xform;
    xform.eM11 = (FLOAT)dpi_x / 96;
    xform.eM12 = xform.eM21 = xform.eM22 = 0;
    xform.eDx = xform.eDy = 0;
    SetWorldTransform(mem_dc, &xform);

    // Copy the screen contents to the bitmap
    if (BitBlt(mem_dc, 0, 0, width, height, screen_dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) == 0) {
        printf("Error:BitBlt failed to copy screen contents to bitmap\n");
        return;
    }

    // Save the bitmap to a file
    Gdiplus::Bitmap image(bitmap, NULL);
    if (image.GetLastStatus() != Ok) {
        printf("Error: Bitmap constructor failed to create a Bitmap object\n");
        return;
    }

    CLSID png_clsid;
    int r = GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &png_clsid);
    if (r == -1)
    {
        printf("Error: unable to find image encoder for MIME type 'image/png'\n");
        return;
    }

    if (image.Save(file_name, &png_clsid, NULL) != Ok) {
        printf("Error: Bitmap::Save failed to save image\n");
        return;
    }

    // Clean up
    SelectObject(mem_dc, old_bitmap);
    DeleteObject(bitmap);
    DeleteDC(mem_dc);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, screen_dc);
}

int main()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT dpi_awareness_context = SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE);

    TakeScreenshot(L"test.png");

    SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(dpi_awareness_context);

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```